# \mathit vs \textit for multi-letter identifiers

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to include a number of two-letter variables in a sentence separated by commas but sometimes there is a noticeable space between the variable and the comma that follows it when I use `mathit`. Although the spaces are not as noticeable in the MWE below.

Is it better to use `textit` instead of `mathit`? If so, how can I ensure the font matches single-letter variables using the same letters (e.g. `$\textit{A}$`)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\textit{AB}, \textit{BA}, \textit{CD}, \textit{DC}

$\mathit{AB}$, $\mathit{BA}$, $\mathit{CD}$, $\mathit{DC}$

$\textit{AB}$, $\textit{BA}$, $\textit{CD}$, $\textit{DC}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges; the right comparison would be between `$AB$` and `$\mathit{AB}$`.

Comment: The spaces between $\mathit{AB}$ and the adjacent comma and $\mathit{CD}$ and its adjacent comma are small in the png marmot included, based on my MWE, but these spaces become larger (and noticeable) when typeset as part of a paragraph. Unfortunately in my industry, $\mathit{AB}$ is the way these identifiers are typeset in equations. I only came across this space being introduced between $\mathit{AB}$ and the adjacent comma when I tried to include several of these identifiers in a paragraph. My strategy now is to avoid using a comma after $\mathit{AB}$ if the gap becomes too wide.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but an attempt to talk you out of this notation.

**UPDATE** This post got feedback from several more experienced users. I agree with all their statements and certainly should have done more research. However, I also feel that their statements provide further reasons for the proposed notation not being optimal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\myvar[1]{\ensuremath{\mathit{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Your options 
\begin{itemize}
 \item \textit{AB}, \textit{BA}, \textit{CD}, \textit{DC}
 \item $\mathit{AB}$, $\mathit{BA}$, $\mathit{CD}$, $\mathit{DC}$
 \item $\textit{AB}$, $\textit{BA}$, $\textit{CD}$, $\textit{DC}$
\end{itemize}
look all the same. In fact, it seems that there is no noticable difference
between these options:\\
\verb|\makebox[0pt][l]{$\mathit{AB}$}$\textit{AB}$|: \makebox[0pt][l]{$\mathit{AB}$}$\textit{AB}$

However, things are different once you wrap these commands in other
environmants:\\
\verb|\textbf{$\mathit{AB}$}|: \textbf{$\mathit{AB}$} vs.\\
\verb|\textbf{$\textit{AB}$}|: \textbf{$\textit{AB}$}\\
\verb|$\left(\mathit{AB}\right)$|: $\left(\mathit{AB}\right)$ vs.\\
\verb|$\left(\textit{AB}\right)$|: $\left(\textit{AB}\right)$

Even the pure math version looks very similar:\\
\verb|\makebox[0pt][l]{$\mathit{AB}$}$AB$|: \makebox[0pt][l]{$\mathit{AB}$}$AB$ 

However, the pure math version comes with different distances:\\
\verb|\makebox[0pt][l]{$\mathit{BA}$}$BA$|: \makebox[0pt][l]{$\mathit{BA}$}$BA$\\
\verb|\makebox[0pt][l]{$\mathit{BA}$}$\textit{BA}$|: \makebox[0pt][l]{$\mathit{BA}$}$\textit{BA}$

You may come up with a command that distinguishes netween math and nonmath
modes: \verb|\newcommand\myvar[1]{\ensuremath{\mathit{#1}}}|

Under boldface, this seems to behave like a math variable should:\\
\verb|\textbf{\myvar{AB}}|: \textbf{\myvar{AB}}\\
\verb|\textbf{$\myvar{AB}$}|: \textbf{$\myvar{AB}$}\\
\verb|\boldmath$\myvar{AB}$\unboldmath|: \boldmath$\myvar{AB}$\unboldmath\\
\verb|\boldmath\myvar{AB}\unboldmath|: \boldmath\myvar{AB}\unboldmath

The main reason for this point is to question whether it is a very wise move to
use this notation. Many people use $AB$ to indicate the
product $A\cdot B$, and $AB$ is virtually indistinguishable from your variable
\myvar{AB}. (I personally write $A\,B$, but get sometimes criticized.)

\paragraph{Bottomline:} Perhaps it is better to use a different notation.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\textbf{We have $\textit{AB}$}` and `\textbf{We have $\mathit{AB}$}`

Comment: See the difference: `$\left(\mathit{B}\right)$` and `$\left(\textit{B}\right)$` The spaces behave differently!

Comment: saying `\textit` is a better choice because it works in text and math is not good advice, generally `\mathit` is better for math and `\textit` is better for text.